# Rcpp - how to use a distribution function in the C++ code

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm writing a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm for a N(0,1) distribution:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector metropolis(int R, double b, double x0){
    NumericVector y(R);
    y(1) = x0;
    for(int i=1; i<R; ++i){
       y(i) = y(i-1);
       double xs = y(i)+runif(1, -b,b)[0];
       double a = dnorm(xs, 0, 1)[0]/dnorm(y(i), 0, 1)[0];
       NumericVector A(2);
       A(0) = 1;
       A(1) = a;
       double random = runif(1)[0];
       if(random <= min(A)){
            y[i] = xs;
       }
   }
   return y;
}
```

but every time I try to compile the function, this error occurs:

> Line 12: no matching function for call to 'dnorm4'

I tried to write a trivial function using dnorm, like

```
NumericVector den(NumericVector y, double a, double b){
    NumericVector x = dnorm(y,a,b);
    return x;
}
```

and it works. Does someone know why I have this type of error in the Metropolis code?
Are there some other ways to use density functions in the C++ code like in R?

Comment: There are _dozens_ of suitable examples on the Rcpp Gallery, here on SO and other places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within Rcpp there are two sets of samplers - scalar and vector - split by namespaces `R::` and `Rcpp::`. They are divided such that:

- Scalar returns a single value (e.g. `double` or `int`)
- Vector returns multiple values (e.g. `NumericVector` or `IntegerVector`)

In this case, you want to be using the scalar sampling space and *not* the vector sampling space.

This is evident since:

```
double a = dnorm(xs, 0, 1)[0]/dnorm(y(i), 0, 1)[0];
```

Invokes the subset operator `[0]` to obtain the only element in the vector.

---

The second part of this problem is the missing part of the fourth parameter as hinted by

> Line 12: no matching function for call to 'dnorm4'

If you look at the R definition of the `dnorm` function, you see:

```
dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 1, log = FALSE)
```

In this case, you've supplied all but the fourth parameter.

---

As a result, you'll probably want the following:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector metropolis(int R, double b, double x0){
    NumericVector y(R);
    y(1) = x0; // C++ indices start at 0, you should change this!
    for(int i=1; i<R; ++i){ // C++ indices start at 0!!!
        y(i) = y(i-1);
        double xs = y(i) + R::runif(-b, b);
        double a = R::dnorm(xs, 0.0, 1.0, false)/R::dnorm(y(i), 0.0, 1.0, false);
        NumericVector A(2);
        A(0) = 1;
        A(1) = a;
        double random = R::runif(0.0, 1.0);
        if(random <= min(A)){
            y[i] = xs;
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

---

Side note:

C++ indices start at 0 *not* 1. As a result, your vector above is slightly problematic as you being by filling the `y` vector at `y(1)` and not `y(0)`. I'll leave this as an exercise for you to correct though.

Comment: There is also the unaltered interface to R's `Rf_*` functions to I count three.  All this has been discussed at length here and on other places.  Really no need for a new question, but a fine answer.  Thanks, @coatless.