# Compute density using Rcpp sugar function

Tags: rcpp

I want to compute densities of Gamma distribution like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector dg(double sh, double sc){
  return dgamma(seq_len(10)*0.05, sh, sc);
}
```

However this didn't work properly, as I got

```
> dg(10,0.1)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I wonder what is wrong in the code?

EDIT: I want to use the vector version `Rcpp::dgamma` not the scalar version in the `R::` namespace.

Comment: The last parameter of the gamma (and other) density function is whether it should be returned on normal scale or logarithmic scale. Try `Rcpp::dgamma(seq_len(10)*0.05, sh, sc, false)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031275/using-dnorm-with-rcpparmadillo and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384303/rcpp-how-to-use-a-distribution-function-in-the-c-code.

Comment: Here I want the vector version `Rcpp::dgamma`, see [https://teuder.gitbooks.io/introduction-to-rcpp/content/en/21_dpqr_functions.html#gamma-distribution]. The log scale is default to be false so it makes no difference. The links to other questions as suggested are for scalar versions, so I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: You are actually right about the default of `dgamma` and this is not a duplicate  of the referenced answers. The problem is `seq_len(10) * 0.05`. I cannot post it as an answer, but this should work:  `Rcpp::IntegerVector isq = Rcpp::seq_len(10);` and 
  `Rcpp::NumericVector sq = 0.05 * Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericVector>(isq);`, `return Rcpp::dgamma(sq, sh, sc);`. Try to first do things step by step and don't start with too complex expressions.

Comment: Yes it works! I thought it would convert implicitly to NumericVector, like assigning an integer variable to double, but actually you need explicit conversion here.